# How do i remove all objects inside an array when i load the reload the page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic2 (Angular2& typescript).Currently i am working on a matching algorithm where a match is found it will push the result inside an array which is also inside an object. However if i go back to the previous page and try to do another match.It will display results from the previous match.Hence i would want to be able to clear out all the results inside the array/object before proceeding to the matching part.So far i tried using ionwillEnter , and it just give me a blank page.I tried putting it inside the constructor and it does not work.Below are the codes

populating the object

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public testService: TestService,public cameraService: CameraService,public toastCtrl: ToastController,public auth : AuthProvider,af : AngularFire) {

    this.objUser.length = 0; //trying to empty out all the elements/objects inside the array 

    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/user/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/profile/');
    ref.on('value',
      ((data)=>{

        var users = data.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(users);
        console.log(keys);

        for(var y =0; y<keys.length; y++){
          var x = keys[y];

          this.objUser[y] = {userName:'', userAllergies:[], resultWarning:[], resultUnsafe:[]};  //dynamically create objects based on the y value
          console.log(users[x].allergies);

          this.objUser[y].userName = users[x].name;
          this.objUser[y].userAllergies.push(users[x].allergies);
          console.log('userAllergies',this.objUser[y].userAllergies);
          console.log(this.objUser[y].userAllergies.length);

        }

        console.log(this.objUser);
        console.log(this.objUser.length);
      }),
      this.errData);
  }
```

Hence is there anyway that i can remove all elements inside the array and re-initialize everything i load the page?.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'on' method gets triggered for every change in the firebase node (i.e. edit/add/remove). Hence try clearing the array elements inside of 'on' method but not outside of it.